# Reading a word from a file in a specific way

Tags: python, file

So I am trying to store a single word to a file (which i have already managed to figure out how to do). The program would then repeat and ask me to input another word. It should check if this word already exists in the file (which it should). I have it to the point where i have inputted a word and it has stored it in the file but when i input the same word again it doesn't realise that the word already exists in the file. (This is all in a def function so when i say the next time it goes round i mean the next time i call the function)

Here is the code:

```
def define():
    testedWord = subject
    lineNumber = 1
    lineInFile = "empty"
    exists = False
    while lineInFile != "":
        wordsFile = open("Words.txt", "a")
        lineInFile = linecache.getline("Words.txt", lineNumber)
        lineNumber = lineNumber + 1
        lineInFile = lineInFile.replace("\n", "")
        if lineInFile == subject:
            definitionNumber = lineNumber
            exists = True
    if exists == False:
        wordsFile.write(testedWord)
        wordsFile.write("\n")
        wordsFile.close()

subject = input("")
define()
##This whole thing basically gets repeated
```

Like i said, if i store a new word and then in the same program try and put in the same word again then it won't recognize that it has already stored this word. When i stop the program and restart it, it works (but i dont want to have to do that)

Thanks for you help (if it is possible to help lol)
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making (almost) everything more complicated than it needs to be. Here is a different way of doing what you're trying to do:

```
def word_check(f_name, word):

    with open(f_name) as fi:
        for line in fi: # let Python deal with line iteration for you
            if line.startswith(word):
                return # return if the word exists

    # word didn't exist, so reopen the file in append mode
    with open(f_name, 'a') as fo:
        fo.write("{}\n".format(word))

    return

def main():

    f_name = "test.txt"

    with open(f_name, 'w') as fo:
        pass # just to create the empty file

    word_list = ['a', 'few', 'words', 'with', 'one',
                 'word', 'repeated', 'few'] # note that 'few' appears twice

    for word in word_list:
        word_check(f_name, word)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This produces an output file with the following text:

> a
>   few
>   words
>   with
>   one
>   repeated

In this example, I just created a list of words instead of using input to keep the example simple. Note how inefficient your current method is, though. You're reopening a file and reading every line for every word entered. Consider building your word list in memory instead, and writing it out at the end. Here's an implementation that takes advantage of the built-in [set](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#set) datatype. They don't allow repeated elements. If you're okay with writing out the file at the *end* of the program run instead of on-the-fly, you can do this instead:

```
def main():

    word_set = set()

    while True:
        word = input("Please enter a word: ")

        if word == 'stop': # we're using the word 'stop' to break from the loop
            break          # this of course means that 'stop' should be entered 
                           # as an input word unless you want to exit
        word_set.add(word)

    with open('test.txt', 'w') as of:
        of.writelines("{}\n".format(word) for word in word_set)
        # google "generator expressions" if the previous line doesn't
        # make sense to you

    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Printed output:

> Please enter a word: apple
>   Please enter a word: grape
>   Please enter a word: cherry
>   Please enter a word: grape
>   Please enter a word: banana
>   Please enter a word: stop

Produces this file:

> grape
>   banana
>   cherry
>   apple

Comment: Thanks soooo much for your help. This has really helped me in my program. I didn't realise how easy it would have been.